# Pointers type casting

Tags: c

The output of the below code is `0.0000`. What is happening in the code and why the output is `0.0000` or to ask precisely **what happens when we type cast the `int*` to `float*` and print the de-referenced value** in the below code?

```
int main(){
   int i = 10;
   int *p = &i;
   printf("%f\n", *(float*)p);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you wants to correct your code read Digital_Reality's answer. If you were expecting that your code should print `10.0..` then no it is undefined behaviour here is one more link to answer you [In C, if I cast & dereference a pointer, does it matter which one I do first?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634252/in-c-if-i-cast-dereference-a-pointer-does-it-matter-which-one-i-do-first)

Comment: Also see http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/fp/ for an introduction to how floating point numbers are typically stored. (Actually, pretty much universally, but the C language does not mandate this.)

Comment: This violates strict aliasing and invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan ur link helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean?

```
printf("%f\n", (float)*p);
```

Edit: After you clarified your question.

There will be undefined behaviour if you try to convert `Int*` to `float*`. Pointer is a address, and int float are stored in memory in different format. so you can not cast it.

Comment: I think yes OP should cast value instead of address that is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I guess he does intend to ask what he has pasted. He has made it clear in his question too - `when we type cast the int* to float* and print the de-referenced value`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan yes at least %f says so :)

Comment: I want to know what happens if we type cast the int* to float* ie typecasting the memory address and dereferencing the same and also is this kind of type casting common or where it will be used (use case if any)

Comment: This question was asked to me in a interview:)

Comment: @user3148581 read the answers I linked with your question.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan for float* to char* type conversion truncation may happen but int* to float* there is no truncation since they are of same sizes. so why iam not getting 10.0000 but 1.0000. My doubt may be so silly but bear with me:P

Comment: @user3148581 NO size may be different, it depends on platform thats why it is Undefined behavior

Comment: @user3148581 Updated my answer after you clarified the question..

Comment: and you can read link posted by @GrijeshChauhan for detailed answer!

Comment: thank you so much  @Grijesh Chauhan Digital_Reality

Answer (score 1):

The pointer always holds the memory address, which is either 16 bits or 32 bits. You are basically type casting the `Memory address` which is unusual behavior. 
And solution to your problem depends upon what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: How is it unusual to cast an `A*` to a `B*`?