# what does it do *((T**)m_ptr)?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I see this in the code and can't understand what is going here:

```
T * ptr; // we have some pointer and it has proper adress
...
// Later I see this and I can't understand what is going here
ptr = *((T **)ptr);
```

Also, later in the code I see `*((T**)ptr) = m_address;`

What for this construction is used ? 
`*((T**)ptr)`

Thanks!

Comment: It's casting. We are saying that - hey consider this address as `T**` and then dereference it.

Comment: Do you know about *casting*? Do you know about *pointer dereferencing*? Read about them in your text books.

Comment: De-referencing type-casted pointer?

Comment: Duplicate of [in-c-if-i-cast-dereference-a-pointer-does-it-matter-which-one-i-do-first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634252/in-c-if-i-cast-dereference-a-pointer-does-it-matter-which-one-i-do-first) Duplicate of [why-cast-to-a-pointer-then-dereference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39312058/why-cast-to-a-pointer-then-dereference/39312134)

Comment: @coderredoc so why don't you hammer this?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre.: Because it involved 2 tags. If someone has different opinion let me know. Will open it.

Comment: the OP kind of spammed tags. This isn't C++, this is plain C unless proven otherwise. Don't be shy about the hammering, don't wait to get [tag:pointers] gold badge to close this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the author wished they'd written `T** ptr` instead, and are hacking around the fact that they didn't, by casting the pointer to a different type than that which it was declared with, before dereferencing it. It pretends that `ptr` points to `T**` instead of a `T*`.

There are some occasions on which this [*type punning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) is okay (e.g. it's commonly used with the `struct sockaddr` type to sort of implement polymorphism), but type punning `T*` to `T**` is very strange.

In fact, unless `T` is `char`, or `T` has a `T*` as its first member and there's no padding, it's also a code smell (and, as far as I'm aware, UB).

Avoid.

Comment: IMHO, *"Avoid"* makes this whole answer.

Comment: @StoryTeller: "C--------- would not type pun again"